# bootboxjs invalid prompt type - example from documentation doesn't work

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

I am trying to use http://bootboxjs.com/examples.html#bb-prompt in my project, so naturally I started by using their example code to see if it runs.

As per the documentation; I am using latest bootstrap, jquery and bootstrap js and then loading the bootboxjs. This is the code I am trying to run:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: "This is a prompt with a set of radio inputs!",
    message: '<p>Please select an option below:</p>',
    inputType: 'radio',
    inputOptions: [
    {
        text: 'Choice One',
        value: '1',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Two',
        value: '2',
    },
    {
        text: 'Choice Three',
        value: '3',
    }
    ],
    callback: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

When this code executes; I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: invalid prompt type

[image]

This is a pretty sweet library and I'd love to use it in my project; but I am a bit stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I had initially used just `bootbox.min.js` but it turns out I need to use `bootbox.locales.min.js` also. I should've rtfm...

Also, I use webpack (via laravel-mix) to bundle all the libs into one .js file, so using the `bootbox.all.min.js` (Production build with locales) as the last thing I load seemed to have helped also.

This is my `webpack.mix.js` config file that works for me:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix
    .copyDirectory('resources/libs/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
    .styles(
        [
            // snipped...
        ],
        'public/css/app.css'
    )
    .scripts(
        [
            'resources/libs/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',
            'resources/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js',
            // bunch of other js libs...
            'resources/libs/bootbox/bootbox.all.min.js',
        ],
        'public/js/app.js'
    );
```

Comment: Maintainer, here - Yeah, sorry, I've been wondering if it was worth pulling the locales out to a separate file - the idea was to save some bytes by not including all locales, since it seems unlikely that anybody uses more than one or two in any given project. Other than the CDN being out-of-date, issues with locales seems to be the most common problem since I made that change. If you want to raise an issue on the Github project, I'd consider pinning it.

Comment: I think your original issue might have actually been that you were loading version 4.4 - I added radio as an input type when I made my updates for version 5.x. Were you loading from the CDN?

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. I downloaded it from cdnjs.com and bundled it together using webpack as per my answer/example.

Comment: Yep, and unfortunately cdnjs is out of date - I haven't been able to get a successful pull-request pulled in, due to some differences in the repo. Seems like I'll need to do some reversions if I want everything to work as intended.